# Transfer existing Android app to another developer account?

Tags: android, transfer, account

I'm currently working on an application for a small company I work for. I'm happy to, and the company has agreed, that they are happy for me to host the application under my own developer account for now.

If I do this, and later on we transfer the app to the companies own dev account (which I will get setup in the future), will users still receives updates as per normal? They should not have to uninstall and reinstall the app once it's live in the new dev account correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Important: Do not forget that to be able to perform upgrades of transferred application you also need the original certificate that was used for signing the app! If the original developer will not give you their certificate then you can not make future upgrades and will have to start from scratch (no download count ...)

Comment: Is this still accurate in late 2016? It seems a bit ridiculous that Google has a decently well-documented process for transferring app ownership, but doesn't appear to facilitate the transfer of developer credentials in the same way. Apple does a much, *much* better job here.

Comment: does it properly work? and can transfer a single app to another account is it possible ? please guide

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Here is new method to do this**

1. Go to the Developer console
2. In the "Help & Feedback" > "Manage Your Apps" > "Transfer your application"
3. Follow the instructions and make sure you have the details from the suggested checklist available
4. Submit the form
5. You will receive instructions on what to do in about a day.

Once you submit the form you will see the below message:

> Please note, we'll do our best to respond to your request within one business day. This depends heavily on the complexity of your app transfer request, and the completeness and accuracy of the information you've provided. We appreciate your patience while we process your request.

**OLD METHOD:**
You can transfer you app without loosing download count or rating.

The steps to transferring your app/game:

1. click: Developer Home > Help > Contact Support > Developers > Publishing and Distribution Issues
2. Fill out the form completely and accurately
3. Select “Transfer Applications to Another Account” from the Issue Type drop down
4. Submit Form
5. Check your E-Mail and reply with the requested information
6. Forward the E-Mail to the person accepting the app/game transfer and have them reply as requested
7. Wait for Google to wave their magic wand

Here is the link, Hope you find it useful. 
http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be valid anymore.

Comment: @Devius Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's not anymore, you need to go to the dev console, in the help & feedback section go to support, next go to Manage my app and then transfer your applications

Comment: Once you've logged into the Google Play Developer Console, where is this 'Help & Feedback' section??

Comment: Here is link with all the details https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en

Comment: what if transaction id is missed

Comment: can I update the app after submitting the transfer request  / verification mode?

Answer (score 6):

For 2019, follow below steps:

1. Open [Google Support Page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en).
2. Open Transfer apps to a different developer account [form](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser?service=androiddeveloper&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fapps%2Fpublish%2F%23AppTransferPlace&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fapps%2Fpublish%2F&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)
3. Get target account Transaction Id from the [Google Payments](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser?service=billing&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fpayments.google.com%2Fpayments%2Fhome%23&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fpayments.google.com%2Fpayments%2Fhome&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)
4. In Google Payments, Select **Activity** from the side menu which is the first option. From the Activity list choose one of the activity and you will get the **Transaction details** from your right side where you can scroll and check **TRANSACTION ID**

Fill the **Transfer apps to a different developer account form** and google will review and transfer the app.

**Notes:** Google hasn't updated the steps based on new pay.google.com page.

Answer (score 2):

For the **most recent method** for transferring your app, see [this **official guide**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213), which is published by Google Play, and will hopefully remain up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Now you can manage Owner and User Accounts:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

You can add users and grant them permissions to create/draft and publish apps.

So, Basically you ask the final owner create the publish account (as the owner). And only add you/developer (as a user) with proper permissions to upload and update app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately google still only allow the original account holder to do certain tasks.  I've gone along the path of creating a shared email to get around this for a company account.