# How to rename Android project for Play Store

Tags: android

I have been developing an app under my own account and now I want to handover the app to be published under another Google Play account. How does one go about doing this? Do I have to sign the APK against another keystore? Change the application name?

Answer (score 0):

From another Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432408/transfer-existing-android-app-to-another-developer-account):

"You can transfer you app without loosing download count or rating.

The steps to transferring your app/game: 1) click: Developer Home > Help > Contact Support > Developers > Publishing and Distribution Issues 2) Fill out the form completely and accurately 3) Select “Transfer Applications to Another Account” from the Issue Type drop down 4) Submit Form 5) Check your E-Mail and reply with the requested information 6) Forward the E-Mail to the person accepting the app/game transfer and have them reply as requested 7) Wait for Google to wave their magic wand

Here is the link, Hope you find it useful. http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/"

Answer (score 0):

If you mean store listing name, do it from your console. This will rename how it is listed in the store. It will not change ANYTHING ELSE.
[image]

If you mean your internal application name. Go to your strings.xml ( if its defined there)

The application name isn't your application 'id', your application 'id' is your package name, hence changing the name doens't change anything big.