# App transfer account and api key issues

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, transfer

I have an app on GooglePlay using google map api v1 and I would like to transfer my app to another account.

Here is the problem : google no longer generates keys for apimapv1 and as mentioned in google's documentation, "each Google Maps Android API v1 Key is uniquely associated with a specific signing certificate.".

If the transfer occurs, will our signing certificate (keystore files) still be valid on the new account, and will it allow the new account to use the current MapKey API v1 ?

Switching to APIMAPv2 is not an option for the moment.

Comment: Vincent, did you ever get any answers to this question? I'm in the same boat. We will be giving the new owners our keystore files. Is that is all they need?

Answer (score 4):

> I have an app on GooglePlay using google map api v1 and I would like
>   to transfer my app to another account.

I assume you mean to another developer account? Just in case you don't know how to do this properly see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16434317/2310866).

> Here is the problem : google no longer generates keys for apimapv1 and
>   as mentioned in google's documentation, "each Google Maps Android API
>   v1 Key is uniquely associated with a specific signing certificate.".

The reason they are associated is simple: Google doesn't want new apps to use the old API. They do not give out new API keys so only the apps that still have an API key can use the old API. If you transfer your app, it is essentially as if you upload a new app. You would need a new API key and since you can't get one you run into a problem.

I think at this point I should mention that that is a good thing. I know that it might not be an option to upgrade to the new API, but the old API is pretty old by now, nobody should be using it any more. The new API is new for a reason after all.

However you might be able to get Google to give you a new API key, just describe your problem in the transfer form and that you need an API key for the old API. That's your best option I think, and it most likely is the only thing you can do anyway.

> If the transfer occurs, will our signing certificate (keystore files)
>   still be valid on the new account, and will it allow the new account
>   to use the current MapKey API v1 ?

The keys are associated with the signing certificate as noted [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/#apikey). Your only option is to describe your situation to Google and hope that they will give you a new one or at least transfer the old one along with the app.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite understand. I know that the api key is tied to the so called 'signing certificate' but I don't know what a 'singing certificate' is other than my "keystore" file, that I use when exporting a signed APK file from Eclipse. So I will be giving the new owner the keystore because they will need that anyway to update the app. So do I still need a new API key or not in that circumstance? To me a 'signing certificate' is nothing more than some file that I point to when exporting my APK and there is some password for it.Is it somehow linked to my developer account?

Comment: Yes that is the file and it is linked to the app. You cryptographically sign the app to confirm your identity as the developer of the app. The combination of that certificate and the API key ensures that only your app can actually access the API.

Comment: ok yes, so then if I'm transferring my app, the keystore file, and the current v1 api key, then the new owner should still be able to publish updates to that app and have the maps work. Correct? Your answer above says "Your only option..." indicating we need a new API key, but instead we don't need a new API key at all do we? That is what I'm trying to get answered.

Comment: Well theoretically yes, but the important part is that you explain this in the transfer form. Describe your situation and you shouldn't run into any problems.

Comment: I stil don't get it. Why would I need to explain anything in the transfer form? I currently have no problem updating my own app that has a v1 key. If I transfer ownership of that app to a new person and give them my keystore file to sign it with, then why wouldn't it work for them?

Comment: Well you aren't just giving the person your keystore, you are transferring the app. Google wants you to be as specific and detailed as possible in the transfer forms, so all I'm saying is: Describe your situation in the transfer form and you are going to be ok.

Comment: I am giving them my keystore. All my comments above say that I'm giving them my keystore.

Comment: Hi @Fraggle, did you manage to transfer the app successfully? I'm having the same sort of question but with v2 key...

Comment: @Arnaud yes, app transfer was successful, gave new owners my keystore file. No issues.

Comment: @Fraggle well, thank you very much, information is hard to gather on that specific point, I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

See this Link

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

You can add users and grant them permissions to create/draft and publish apps.

So, Basically you ask the final owner create the publish account (as the owner). And only add you/developer (as a user) with proper permissions to upload and update app.