# Android app transferred from another developer account not showing in developer console

Tags: android, google-play, transfer

I was taking over someone else's android project and as such, asked the developer who was working on the project previously to transfer the app.

I found numerous resources on how to initiate the transfer including:

[Transfer existing Android app to another developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432408/transfer-existing-android-app-to-another-developer-account/16434317#16434317)

And the page on Google developer help dedicated to app transfers.

I have given the previous developer all the information required including the  transaction ID, and it seems that the process has gone smoothly, he forwarded me this email:
    Your transfer is complete!

```
Thanks for providing the necessary info for your application transfer. 

Thanks for supporting Google Play!

Regards, 
*****
Google Play Developer Support
```

So naturally, I wanted to push an update to the application, but it is nowhere to be seen in the developer console. Furthermore, could not find any info about the receiving end of app transfer on either Google play help, Stack Overflow or elsewhere.

Upon trying to find a contact point for this issue, I found myself lost, Google developer help offers only very specific topics and is more like an automated service than anything, even found this open letter:

http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/05/open-letter-please-help-yourself-to-helping-yourself-why-google-needs-to-rethink-the-concept-of-developer-support/

Have anyone experienced anything similar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It can take a couple of days before it is processed.

Comment: @NiekHaarman Thank you for the reply, i thought so myself but it has been over 10 days, so I was getting worried

Comment: It took a lot shorter for me. I think the best solution is to contact support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem on Google's side as Niek Haarman suggested.

If anyone faces something similar, this is what I did to contact Google:

I went to https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/ and clicked Contact Us.

As app transfer does not offer email option, I went for

```
Publishing apps on Google Play > Published app isn't showing on Google Play
```

And described the issue.

Google contacted me the same day completing the transfer